# Built-in (or external framework) method in the iOS sdk to convert a string with HTML &xxx; sequences to plain characters?

Tags: iphone, html, tags, nsstring

Is there a built-in way in the iOS sdk to take an NSString containing HTML sequences

```
& amp;, & nbsp;, & lt;  (spaces added to avoid markdown interpretation)
```

etc., and translate those to '&', ' ', '<' ?    My string contains international UTF8 characters so I can't convert to ascii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Waterfall has commented on other, similar questions, there is no built-in function available, but have a look at [his solution](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) which is a new category for NSString.

It defines the following new methods, especially `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities`:

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```